# Get user details from Twitter

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm creating a web application with php and JavaScript that will get a user's details from twitter. I have tried reading the documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show but could't understand anything. I found very little relevant documentation on the subject. I need to see a sample code for a tutorial. Anyone with Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i would handle this is by using:

```
$username = ''; // Twitter Username
$page_data = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?include_entities=true&screen_name=$username");
```

Then search `$page_data` for the specific details you want, using `preg_match()` to match regex patterns for the data you're looking for.

I also found this, which is along the same lines, but without regex.

http://tareq.wedevs.com/2009/05/playing-with-twitter-json-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

Take my Twitter account, for example. My screen name is `charliekilian`. So if you go to this URL:

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=charliekilian&include_entities=true

you will get back a JSON entity about my account. In other words, you issue the request via HTTP GET, and it will respond with a document that is structured as a JSON object that you can parse to figure out the data.

If you want data on a different user, replace the portion of the URL that is my username with the username you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Charlie. Can I make a querry like the facebook login such that when I click login with twitter I get user details? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to allow users of your site to log on to your site using their Twitter account?

Comment: Yes but when they login I want to get the user details and store them in my application. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to use the Twitter username & password to log in to your own site, at the moment, appears to be via OAuth 1.0.  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq  2.0 is not yet supported.

Comment: Take a look through https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter - step 3 is the point where you get the user_id and screen_name of the visitor who's signed in with twitter. You would store these values, and then use the API call Charlie's provided to get the rest of the user details you want.